# Why functions declared inside return of IIFE are name so?

Tags: javascript

```js
const ui = (function() {

  let ourvar = 'iffe called!!!';

  return {

    func_1: function() {
      console.log(ourvar)
    }

  }
})();

console.log(ui.func_1())
```

Here notice the function inside the return. Its named `func_1:function(){}` instead of the normal conventional way of naming functions which is `function func_1(){}`. Why is it named here so?

Why wouldn't normal function declaration method work here?

Thanks

Comment: Because... it wouldn't work if you did? All it's doing is returning an object with an `xyz` key...

Comment: No, it's not named, it's an anonymous function expression. It's located in an object literal `{func_1: …}` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIFE is returning an object. An object contains key value pairs. So in your code func_1 is the key that has the value of a function. All these are valid ways to declare it:

```
return  {
    xyz: function() {}
}
```

Or

```
return  {
    xyz: function abc() {}
}
```

Or you can declare the function using normal syntax and refer it inside the object literal like this:

```
function abc() {}
return {
    xyz: abc
}
```

In ES6 you can use even this syntax:

```
return  {
    xyz() {}
}
```

You can't use the normal function declaration syntax inside object literals like:

```
return {
    function xyz() {}
}
```

This makes no sense. This is like:

```
return {
    var a = 10
}
```

which also makes no sense inside an object literal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function declaration and then reference it in the object literal.

Using a function expression is shorter.

```js
const ui = (function() {
  let ourvar = 'iffe called!!!';


  function func_1() {
    console.log(ourvar)
  }

  return {
    func_1
  };
})();

console.log(ui.func_1())
```

Comment: Okay...From what I understand just because it is inside an object, We define a key to this anonymous function...

Also since its returning an object literal, the conventional way of function will not work? 
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, functions are first class, meaning that they can be treated like any other variable.

In your example, you could do this instead:

```
const func_1 = function() {
     console.log(ourvar);
}

return {
     func_1: func_1
}
```

In javascript you can also shorten this to just:

```
return {
    func_1
}
```